# Attempt to read property "name" on null laravel-9 crud

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-9

Would you like to help me: I try to patch data in edit stage CRUD laravel but got some errors:

> Attempt to read property "name" on null

I have no idea what makes this error, I have right called the column in testimoni table name "name" but I get this error.

Here is my `index.blade.php`

```
<a href="{{ url('/admin/testimonial/edit' . $testi->id .'/edit')}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-block bg-gradient-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button></a>
```

I defined $testimonial as $testi

Here is my controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $testimoni = Testimoni::find($id);
    return view('admin.testimonial.edit')->with('testimonial', $testimoni);
}
```

And here is my edit.blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('testimonial.update') }}" method="post">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                @method('PATCH')
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nama</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{$testimoni->name}}">
                  </div>
```

My route:

```
  Route::resource('/admin/testimonial', TestimoniController::class);
```

I try to change parameter on my form link but still got an error, I hope you understand my question. Thank you.

Comment: `->with('testimonial', $testimoni);`, then `{{ $testimoni->name }}`? You should get an error `undefined variable $testimoni`; you're naming it `$testimonial` via `->with('testimonial', $testimoni)`, so it should be `{{ $testimonial->name }}`. And even then; `::find($id)` **can still return `null`**. Use `::findOrFail($id)`.

Comment: Your route is wrong. [For resource controllers, the route](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) would be `/admin/testimonial/' . $testi->id .'/edit`. As of right now, the id being passed in would be `edit1` instead of `1`

Comment: thanks guys, i have changed several code first calling this in value `{{ $testimonial->name }}` and the link into `'/admin/testimonial/' . $testi->id .'/edit'`, and also change my form action to `{{ route('testimonial.update', ['testimonial' => $testimonial->id]) }}` and its works, your anwers really help me, thank you so much. @TimLewis @aynber

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear it's working  You could improve this a bit more by changing `public function edit($id)` to `public function edit(Testimoni $testimonial)`, and delete  `$testimoni = Testimoni::find($id);` for [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding). Sidenote, `Testimonial` should be the Model name, and you should stop trying to shorten/lengthen it; a major cause of your issue here is using `$testi`, `$testimoni`, `'testimonial'`, `$testimonial`, etc... Pick one and be consistent with your naming 

Comment: @TimLewis
i tried to change several name like `testimoni` table become `testimonials` table, and `TestimoniController` become `TestimonialController` also model become `Testimonial`.
but when i run `Route::resource('/admin/testimonial', TestimonialController::class);`
it direct me to 404 page. so i check the routing name on cmd and got the error   
`ReflectionException
Class "TestimonialsController" does not exist`
i once have TestimonialsController::class but already fix it, but the error still

Comment: There's a lot to unpack in that comment lol... Model should be `Testimonal` (singular), Controller be can `TestimonialController` or `TestimonialsController` (it can be either, up to you), so long as you name it same as your filename: `public class TestimonialsController { ... }` should be `TestimonialsController.php`. Then make sure your `namespace` matches, so `app\Http\Controllers\Admin\TestimonialsController.php` should have `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin`. Lastly, importing it should be `use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TestimonialsController`, then  `TestimonialsController::class`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you do it so back by with keyword and ...

For simple crud you must do something like this.

```
// Route
Route::groupt(['prefix'=>'admin'],function(){
   Route::resource('testimonial', TestimoniController::class);
});

// Edit Method

public function edit(Testimonial $testimonial){
   return view('path.to.blade',compact('testimonial'));
}

// Or

public function edit($id)
{
    $testimonial = Testimoni::findOrFail($id);
    return view('path.to.blade',compact('testimonial'));
}


// Blade

<input type="text" value="{{old('name',$testimonial->name)}}">
```

i think this code will help you.

you must return 404 if user open none exist items.